# Any good reference for homotopy colimit of $\mathrm{hTop}$ category?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Let

$\mathrm{Top}$: the category where objects are topological spaces and morphisms are continuous maps.

$\mathrm{hTop}$: the category where objects are topological spaces and morphisms are homotopy class of continuous maps.

$\mathrm{Ho}:\mathrm{Top}\rightarrow \mathrm{hTop}$: the functor sending $f$ to $[f]$ for any continuous map $f$.

I'm beginner of homotopy theory and learning the notion of homotopy colimit from the CH8 of "Cubical Homotopy Theory" by Munson-Volić. In that book, the authors develop the theory of homotopy colimit for the category $\mathrm{Top}$, but I am looking for good textbook/reference for the homotopy colimit for the category $\mathrm{hTop}$.

For example, I want to find a reference having analogous version of the following Theorem 8.3.7 in Munson-Volić's book:

"Let $F,G:\mathrm{I}\rightarrow\mathrm{Top}$ be two functors and $N:F\rightarrow G$ are natural transformation such that $F(i)\rightarrow G(i)$ is homotopy equivalence for any $i\in \mathrm{I}$. then, the natural map $\mathrm{hocolim}F\rightarrow\mathrm{hocolim}G$ is homotopy eauivalence."

I'm expecting the similar result will still hold even if $N$ is a natural transformation in $\mathrm{hTop}^{\mathrm{I}}$, from $\mathrm{Ho}\circ F$ to $\mathrm{Ho}\circ G$. But I couldn't find any good references. I did some googleing, but the references I found were too advanced or abstract to me. So, I hope to know what are some good (accessible to beginners, requiring less background material, having many examples,...) resources for the homotopy colimit of $\mathrm{hTop}$ category.

Comment: Homotopy (co)limits are not taken of diagrams in the homotopy category of Top, instead they are taken of diagrams in Top itself. So presumably the result you stated is the one you want  to be using.

Comment: @Connor Malin Yes. the analogous result I mentioned is what I want to use.

Comment: What is the definition homotopy colimit of a diagram in $hTop$? There isn't one as far as I know, so the question does not make sense to me.

Comment: @Connor Malin I see your point. I edited my question to clarify. Thank you.

Comment: Are you asking for a colimit in $hTop$? Because these things don't exist in general. If you are suggesting to lift the diagrams from $hTop$ back to $Top$ and then form homotopy colimits, then there is no 'natural map' induced by a natural transformation in $hTop$. You can often make sense of a well-defined homotopy type at the level of the homotopy category (eg. homotopy fiber/cofiber, homotopy pushout/pullback, etc...) but these things are not natural unless you use the data of maps, homotopies, etc...